# I am getting an error in my in my sql on line 12, or near 'order ON order-user_id = user.id. Any thoughts? Thanks

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

```
SELECT order.date,
   vehicle.year, 
   vehicle.make, 
   vehicle.model, 
   SUM(part.price * order_details.quantity) AS price, 
   order.paid 
FROM vehicle
INNER JOIN user 
   ON user.id = vehicle.user_id
INNER JOIN order 
   ON order.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN order_details 
   ON order_details.order_id = order.id
INNER JOIN part 
   ON part.id = order_details.part_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER is a reserved keyword in most SQL implementations; you probably need to delimit the tablename using a backtick.

```
SELECT `order`.date,
   vehicle.year, 
   vehicle.make, 
   vehicle.model, 
   SUM(part.price * order_details.quantity) AS price, 
   `order`.paid 
FROM vehicle
INNER JOIN user 
   ON user.id = vehicle.user_id
INNER JOIN `order` 
   ON `order`.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN order_details 
   ON order_details.order_id = `order`.id
INNER JOIN part 
   ON part.id = order_details.part_id
```